# I have implemented Native Express Ad in Listview. but when ad refresh , it refresh the listview .

Tags: android, listview, admob

I have implemented Native Express Ad in Listview. but when ad refresh , it refresh the listview and set position it to ad . means it scroll the listview automatic to native ad .Even if ad don't refresh , thought it scroll to ad . that is I don't want to . I don't know how to do this . and why this is auto scroll my listview.

My native ad code is as follows.
 **in holder class.**

```
RelativeLayout adViewContainer;
adViewContainer = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adMobView);
```

**In Adapter class**

```
holder.adViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.adViewContainer.removeAllViews();
        NativeExpressAdView mAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(context);
        mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(320, 300));
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(Constant.ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID);
        holder.adViewContainer.addView(mAdView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behaviour. To block this, add the below **XML** code line to your root level view of your **ListView** (for example: Your top level RelativeLayout)

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```